# Redirect system calls like fopen/open/etc. on macOS/Darwin

Tags: c, macos, unix, system-calls, osdev

I want to redirect system calls like fopen/open/... on macOS.
On Linux ptrace allows me to handle system calls and implement a custom handler, do any of you know any solutions for macOS?

Ideal result: App X wants to open a file, calls UNIX open() (indirectly) --> My App Y catches that call and returns a predefined result. App X is a child process of Y (otherwise, it would have serious security implications)

Why? I am building a sandbox, ideally, the solution allows me to implement a custom system call table

Thanks in advance,
thejakck

Comment: You can't redirect the system calls, as such, but you can intercept the library functions which are typically used. (Also, `fopen` isn't a system call, at all.) You would use [dyld interposing](https://www.google.com/search?q=dyld+interposing) for that.

Comment: man ptrace; Also valgrind does this and more; the source is available.

Comment: @mevets In my understanding, ptrace is strippen on macOS, it cannot do that